# Loop in each() in combination with prepend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, prepend

I want to move HTML-Tags (in this case the Icon) in the DOM.

my HTML Markup looks like this:

```
<li class="linklist__item">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]">Lorem</a>
</li>
<li class="linklist__item">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]">Lorem</a>
</li>
```

and shoul look like this:

```
<li class="linklist__item">      
  <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Lorem</a>
</li>
<li class="linklist__item">      
  <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Lorem</a>
</li>
```

and my JS like this:

```
  const linklistItem = this.$('.linklist__item');
  const linklistLink = this.$('.linklist__item .linklist__link');
  const linklistIcon = this.$('.linklist__item i');
  linklistItem.each(function () {
    linklistLink.prepend(linklistIcon);
  })
```

Sadly there are several Icons added. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the reference to `this / being / window`?

Comment: _"Sadly there are several Icons added"_ because `'.linklist__item i'` matches every icon.

Comment: @Andreas That makes sense. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".linklist__link").prepend(function() {
  return $(this).prev(".fa")
})
```

```css
li a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="linklist__item">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right">ICON</i>
    <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]">Lorem</a>
  </li>
  <li class="linklist__item">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right">ICON</i>
    <a href="#" class="link linklist__link teasable__open" title="[Link title]">Lorem</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.